# Xpath returning same result

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Trying to use Xpath to scrape card name off the following website, https://www2.trollandtoad.com/buylist/?_ga=2.123753418.115346513.1562026676-1813285172.1559913561#!/M/10591, but it keeps returning the same result each time.  I need it to output all the card names from that link, but it just gives me the same one over and over again.

```
def parse(self, response):
        #  Initialize item to function GameItem located in items.py, will be called multiple times
        item = GameItem()
        # Extract card category from URL using html code from website that identifies the category.  Will be outputted before rest of data
        for data in response.css('tr.ng-scope'):
            item["Set"] =data.css("a.ng-binding.ng-scope::text").get()
            if item["Set"] == None:
                item["Set"] = data.css("span.ng-binding.ng-scope::text").get()
            item["Card_Name"]  = data.xpath("//div/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(@class,'buylist_productname item')]/a/text()").get()
```

I tried using getall() but it would not work correctly either.  It would give back all the card names but it would not be paired with the other data I scraped correctly. Instead of outputting one card name for one price and so on it would give me all the card names in one line along with the price for the first card and so on.

Comment: It is unclear what your expected output is. What do you mean by "it keeps returning the same result each time"? Please edit your question to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: @MathiasMüller I need it to return every card name from that website, like 168 different ones but instead it returns the same card name 168 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **relative** XPath:

```
item["Card_Name"]  = data.xpath(".//td[2]/a/text()").get()
```

**UPDATE** Fixed your XPath

Comment: I have already tried that and it just returns null for each value instead.

Comment: @Timmy Oh, your XPath was wrong. See updated answer.